# Aplicação com Tomcat e Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Olá!

Estou com seguinte problema em minha aplicação. Depois de executar o método main logo abaixo e digitar no navegador o endereço da minha aplicação **localhost:9090/restauranteWeb** está abrindo um popUp pedindo usuário e senha, achei que seria do tomcat, mas meu tomcat foi instalado sem usuário e senha. Se alguém já passou por isso e puder ajudar eu agradeço!

```
@SpringBootApplication()
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**PopUp que aparece no navegador, o erro no fundo e depois de clicar em cancelar**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá. O Spring Boot inicia com um Tomcat próprio por padrão, caso contrário ele não executa esse método `main` apresentado na pergunta. Se você diz que instalou outro Tomcat e está executando o `main`, então você tem dois Tomcats diferentes, um vazio e outro com o Spring Boot. O que você precisa fazer é prestar atenção no log de inicialização do Spring Boot, pois ele vai dizer em qual endereço está inicializado. Se não conseguir resolver, por favor, edite sua pergunta adicionando mais detalhes sobre esse Tomcat e também o log, senão não tem como adivinhar o problema. Abraço!

Comment: Ok, obrigado utluiz.

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente no seu arquivo **pom.xml** você está com a seguinte dependência:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Essa dependência faz parte do pacote **Spring Security** que é usado para controle de usuário e outras coisas.
Para entender como usar o Spring Security na sua aplicação, clique [aqui](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/).

Answer (score 2):

Essa mensagem é exibida quando a autenticação `Http Basic` estiver ativa pelo Spring Security, ao contrário das outras respostas, você não deve remover a dependência do seu projeto, visto que ela pode ser ncessária no futuro e o problema acabe voltando.

Para resolver o problema de fato, você deve configurar o Spring para desabilitar a autenticação `Http Basic`, para isso adicione a seguinte linha ao arquivo `application.properties`:

`security.basic.enabled=false`

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você tenha a dependência do *`spring-security`* no seu projeto.

Segundo a documentação do spring boot, se você tiver o spring-security no seu classpath, o spring-boot irá configurar automaticamente seu projeto com Basic.

> If Spring Security is on the classpath then web applications will be secure by default with ‘basic’ authentication on all HTTP endpoints.

Dê uma olhada [aqui](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security).

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente você está com a dependência do Spring Security no seu pom.xml

Basta remover essa dependência e executar o projeto novamente.